# unable to install .deb file through terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, eclipse, deb

I'm in confusion because I'm not getting my eclipse even after installing. I downloaded `.tar.gz` file of eclipse. Then I generated `.deb` file using command:
sudo alien -d eclipse.tar.gz

Then I tried to install it using command:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./eclipse_1-2_all.deb
```

It didn't give me any error and seemed to have worked but there's no eclipse application in dash home. What should I do? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Why not use Ubuntu Software Center? This is Ubuntu, there is no need to download.

Comment: AFAIK you are supposed to extract the zip file and run the installer.

Comment: What is the output of `which eclipse`?

Comment: I've downloaded more than 200 mb, just to install it, I don't think I'm going to use software center for this. I've done this twice with the same file and there was no problem then, but this once this is creating the problem.

Comment: Eclipse platform : the java IDE

Comment: Not sure what you did and why, but the downloaded version of eclipse usually creates a `.desktop` file *on first run*. In other words, before that, you will not find it in Dash. If your executable is not in $PATH, you can find it by looking inside your `.deb` file. Creating a `.deb.` file of it seems a needless step however.

Comment: Is there nothing I can do, instead of reinstalling it from another source?

Comment: Well, you got some suggestions. Did you try any of it? You didn't answer the request for information, what more would you like us to do?

Comment: And another one [How to Install Software when you're a Windows user](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)

Comment: I've applied the first suggestion. Thanks for That.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got the solution after a lot of time. I've been missing jdk in my ubuntu that's why .sh files were unable to be run. I got this idea while installing pycharm but I had to install eclipse from synaptic package manager. Thanks to all for your suggestions.